# Apply function in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame named Cat. I have multiple columns. In one vector named
Jan.15_Transaction I have values. I want to apply a condition that if value is greater than 0 then 1 else 0. So I do not want to use if else condition as there are 42 columns similar to this in which I want to apply the same the same logic.

```
Jan.15_Transaction   Feb.15_Transaction  
1                         1    
2                         2  
3                         3  
4                         4
```

Hence I build this function

```
myfunc <- function(x){
if(x > 0){
  x=1
} 
else {
  x=0
}
return(x)
}
```

This is getting applied to first element only when I use this code.

```
Cat$Jan.15_Transaction.1<-myfunc(Cat$Jan.15_Transaction)
```

Warning message:
In if (x > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

So I tried sapply and got this error below

```
sapply(Cat$Jan.15_Transaction.1, myfunction(Cat))
```

Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Comment: Maybe `cbind(mydf, as.numeric(mydf[, mySubsetofColumns] > 0))` ?

Comment: Please add the error message to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ifelse` function to vectorise (= apply across a vector) an `if` statement:

```
myfunc = function (x)
    ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
```

Alternatively, you could use the following which is more efficient (but less readable):

```
myfunc = function (x)
    as.integer(x > 0)
```

Coming back to your original function, your way of writing it is very un-R-like. A more R-like implementation would look like this:

```
myfunc = function (x)
    if (x > 0) 1 else 0
```

— No need for a temporary variable, assignments, or the `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks Rudolph. It helps.                                                                              I have 42 columns in which I want to use this my func. Is there a way around to select those specific columns , apply the function and show the results by creating a separate vectors in the same data frame.

Comment: If all columns are numeric you can just use ifelse on the whole data.frame like `ifelse(dat>0,1,0)`. Otherwise have a look at `apply`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to apply the function on columns which have names ending with '_Transaction'. This can be done with the base function `grepl`.

```
vars <- grepl('_Transaction', names(df))
df[, vars] <- ifelse(df[, vars] > 0, 1, 0)
```

You could also use `dplyr` like shown below. This would generalize to more complicated functions too.

```
binarizer <- function(x) ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)

df <- bind_cols(
  df %>% select(-ends_with('_Transaction')),
  df %>% select(ends_with('_Transaction')) %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(binarizer))
)
```

Comment: Error: could not find function "bind_cols" i cannot find bind_cols

Comment: The `bind_cols` function is a part of the `dplyr` package.